# How to call a web service with .ashx extention in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, ashx

Want to call a web service with .aspx extension. It cannot add to web references.Then I used webclient and return string. But then I do not Know how to use it. This is my code.

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();

 detail.Title = client.DownloadString("https://somename/cruiseproducts.ashx");
 return downloadedString;
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what is returned by you service

for example

you ashx service should look like this

```
public class TestHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

on your side client code should look like this

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

var testResult = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:19238/TestHandler.ashx");
    return testResult;
```

Noitice that service is returning `"plain/text"` type

if service is returning xml type then u can simply get string firstly and then parse like this

```
//consider that result is in testResult variable
var xml = new XmlDocument();

//your xml tree
xml.LoadXml(testResult);
```

Comment: without adding ashx handler I got the result. then how to use it, because it does not appear xml tags. and thnx for your reply @Gtopuria

Comment: I didn't use any handler @Gtopuria

Comment: what type is returned by service xml? and you want to parse or what's the issue?

Comment: *when we enter the url in the browser it show xml content.
*then it returns the whole xml content without tags. that means plain text only

Comment: if you service is returning xml then you must create XmlDocument variable and then use function LoadXml() and this will parse your returned string to xml , i will update answer

Comment: ok, I meant the only the url shows xml result and my code returns only plaintext  

*this gives the url(xml)
<Name>MS SUNRISE SERMIRAMIS COLLECTION</Name>
<Description>
<p>Our Selected Nile Cruise <b>MS Sunrise Semiramis</b> <b>Collection Nile Cruise</b> the world’s greatest open air museum, to Aswan. Be enchanted by the fascinating landscape and


*my code returns following
3706MS SUNRISE SERMIRAMIS COLLECTION<p>Our Selected Nile Cruise <b>MS Sunrise Semiramis</b> <b>Collection Nile Cruise</b> the worldâ€™s greatest open air museum, to Aswan. Be enchanted by the fascinating landscape a

Comment: I'm checking now. should I create ashx handler for this.

Comment: no you should not , test it on exiting handler you have

Comment: but I didn't create any handler previously, is it okay

Comment: in handler is meant service you are calling with client.DownloadString("handler/service url.ashx")